# Lync 2010 - Primary key relationship betweeen QOS and CDR database records

Tags: lync, qos

Does anyone know what tables/fields are used to uniquely tie the records in the "lcsCDR" call detail records database to the Quality of Service "QOEMetrics" db?
Currently using CnfDateTime but it does not give exact match for some reason!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Got it. For anyone who comes up against this straight forward but severly undocumented problem it is - Table Dialogue in both dB's and DialougID!!